# Sleep connection - strange increase

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling

I use a connection pool from java with this configuration:

```
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
maxActive="400"
maxIdle="30"
validationQuery="Select 1" 
validationInterval="60000"
testOnBorrow="true"
```

Today, 
sleep connection are increased for no reason (see png)

[image: (Dropbox) Image showing increased sleep connections]

Violet -> is connection in sleep

Blue -> is connection in work

Why?
My configuration is wrong?

Thanks,
Carlo

Comment: How many were in sleep? Where's png?

Comment: @Veger: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74145437/Schermata%202014-12-17%20alle%2013.10.59.png

Answer (score 0):

This looks normal to me. At some point your app became busy and needed more than 30 connections.

Then, when things quieted down, the pooling code obeyed `maxIdle=30`, and dropped all the connections except the ones you see.

This is nothing to worry about.

Comment: blue is connection working and violet is connetion in sleep.
Before the increase, connection sleep are more of connection in working. Whi the system has increment the connection instead of using conection in sleeping?